# OBIEE 12C: HTML caching for downloadable file

Tags: html, obiee

I've made an analysis in OBIEE which searches for a file in the analyticsRes folder on the server.

The column formula looks like this : `'<a href="http://xxx:9402/analyticsRes/Documents/'||"Afdeling"."Afdeling Code"||'_extragegevens.docx">'||"Afdeling"."Afdeling"||'</a>'`

It downloads the correct file according to the filter you're applying on the dashboard. This works perfectly fine, except for browser cache.

We found out that the browser caches the file behind this link, so when a new one is put on the server, the old one still gets downloaded.

Can I disable browser cache for this analysis only OR for the whole dashboard (is this a good idea?) so that users will always download the newest version of the file?

I've tried adapting the instanceconfig.xml file according to this:

```
<ServerInstance>
<Cache>
<CatalogXml>
<!-- Remove from the cache everything older than N minutes -->

<MaxAgeMinutes>240</MaxAgeMinutes>
<MaxLastAccessedSeconds>14400</MaxLastAccessedSeconds> </CatalogXml>
</Cache> </ServerInstance>
```

But this isn't the cache used for my issue.

I expect the analysis to be able to always look on the server for the file, but now it caches the file for a long time. It would be also okay if the cache would expire after 24h.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. You have zero influence on browser cache from inside OBIEE. The cache above is OBIPS cache, not browser cache.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea how we can bypass this issue? The only 'solution' I've found so far is restarting OBI.

Comment: Let's be precise here: What do you mean "restarting OBI"?